Strapi merge hosts
Help me to understand,
There is an admin panel on Strapi, and there is a client personal account, now everyone opens on their own host,
how can they be combined?
To /admin - open strapi,
and /client opened the client’s website on one host
I can’t really find anything in the documentation! At least a link and preferably with an example
